# Vectors in python

Tags: python-3.x

Hi i have just started using python and coding in general. This is the last question of my assignment and i honestly have no clue as to how to even start this question.
I need to write a program to do basic vector calculations in 3 dimensions:
addition, dot product and normalization.

I have no clue what to do after this step or if this step is even right please help.

```
The expected result is:
Enter vector A:
1 3 2
Enter vector B:
2 3 0
A+B = [3, 6, 2]
A.B = 11
|A| = 3.74
|B| = 3.61
```

Answer (score 0):

- Using `numpy`:

  ```
  import numpy as np

  A = np.array([1,3,2])
  B = np.array([2,3,0])

  # sum
  print(A+B) # -> array([3, 6, 2])

  # dot product
  print(np.dot(A)) # -> 11

  #normalization
  print(np.linalg.norm(A)) # -> 3.741...
  print(np.linalg.norm(B)) # -> 3.605...
  ```
- Without `numpy`:

  ```
  A = [1,3,2]
  B = [2,3,0]

  # sum
  print([i+j for i,j in zip(A,B)])

  # dot product
  print(sum(i*j for i, j in zip(A,B)))

  #normalization
  print(sum(i**2 for i in A)**(0.5))
  print(sum(i**2 for i in B)**(0.5))
  ```

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without using numpy?

Comment: Of course. Note that `numpy`, from a design perspective, gives better performance in terms of memory and speed.

Comment: last question, when i use negative inputs it does not work, how do i fix this

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: my code only allows positive inputs from the user to work, what would i need to do to have the code accept negative inputs as well?

Comment: you can start another question, so you can explain your problem and your code. Regarding this question, please accept the answer.